# How do I compile and view a tex document using WinEdt7.0?

Tags: winedt

I have just dowloaded WinEdt7.0 and I want to compile and view a `.tex` document with `.bib` file that I've already created and viewed using TeXShop.  The way I would do this in TeXShop would be:

1. Switch my typeset to TeX and Ghostscript.
2. Run LaTeX
3. Run BibTeX
4. Run LaTeX
5. Run LaTeX again

I haven't found any concise instructions on how to do the same thing on WinEdt.  The menu and options seem much more extensive and overwhelming than TeXShop.  How do I accomplish this simple, fundamental task on WinEdt7.0?

Comment: TeXworks is not too different from TeXShop and runs also in Windows.

Comment: It seems to me that WinEdt relies on TeXify for compile chains …

Comment: @Paul, check if you have Miktex installed looking for it on the windows start menu.

Comment: @Sigur:  Thanks.  I just downloaded the latest version of MikTex, and now it seems to work perfectly.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great. I don't know if you have the serial for it. Anyway, if you want you can use a free editor, texmaker. Nice editor.

Comment: @Sigur: One last thing:  my .tex file works fine, except that the bibliography does not display.  I tried SHIFT-CTRL-B, but I get a message saying "I found no \bibdata command---while reading file my-file.tex.  Then it gives me several warnings saying "I didn't find a database entry for "first:citation", etc...  What does this mean?

Comment: Do you have a `.bib` file on your folder? Have you included it in your `.tex` file? You can look for topics related to BibTeX.